# why i am not able get exact value from sql developer to target file or target table?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, excel-2010, informatica

I have two environment Prod and QA, when i try to get the value from Prod table, i got the exact value from Prod table but when i try to get the value from QA table, one decimal value is missing . I tried this requirement in both Python and Informatica but facing same issue in both , still struggling to the get exact value

some of example of my data:

source: SQL developer
target: flat file generated by Informatica

source value:-9.666666666666666
target value:-9.66666666666667

source value:-9.444444444444445
target value:-9.44444444444445

source value:-9.529411764705882
target value:-9.52941176470588

Here you can see for some values are getting rounding off at the end and some values one decimal is missing.
but strange thing is values are present there,when i try to get the difference between QA and Prod vales, i could see the difference when i expected ,  but not able to see the QA exact value.

first of all i thought its problem with Informatica source or target precision , i tried to give max precision across all over mapping, but there is no issue at  precision.

I tried to change the flat file with oracle table but still not getting exact same value.

Here another strange thing is, both QA and Prod table are same schema, everything is same including data types and precision, don't know where is the problem

Please share your thought, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi - it's not very clear what the context is of what you are asking. You've fot "SQL developer" as a source but that is not possible as that's an app used to manage databases. Are you seeing this behaviour only when you are moving data from a source to a target using Informatica? If so, what is the datatype in the source/target for this column (if they are databases) and what is the datatype of each port this column passes through in Informatica?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A number of issues can be causing this. Try the following:

1. Check your SQL Client if it's not rounding up numbers for the display
2. Verify if Enable High Precision is set in session properties in Informatica and check [this article](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/advanced-workflow-guide/high-precision-data/decimal.html) for more details
3. Check precision and scale across whole mapping, for all ports
4. Send data to a flat file and verify the results